# Custom contract on a LogReceiverService Nlog

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm having at the moment a big solution with different projects sending logs with **Nlog** to **LogReceiverService** target.

I would like to use an interface so I have only 1 installation of Nlog in 1 project of my solution.
So I created a new interface to call instead of `NLog.LogReceiverService.ILogReceiverClient` *(inherited from it)* but when I initialize my logger, it's still looking for the contract `NLog.LogReceiverService.ILogReceiverClient`

Is this a normal operation. Is there a way to change this contract?